# NameError and ValueError in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Why is python shell throwing a NameError where as windows console a ValueError?

```
def PrintArgs(*arg):
    list = ['1','2']
    for i in arg:
        try:
            print(list[int(i)])
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter integer value')
        except NameError:
            print('Name Error')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PrintArgs(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Providing the following arguments to Windows Console gives this output:

Here is how I call the code in windows console:

```
C:\>C:\Python34\python C:\Users\User\Documents\PYTest\Test.py 0 a

1
Please enter integer value
```

Providing the following arguments to Python Shell does not display the cusom error for NameError as mentioned in the code above, but mentions the following error:

```
PrintArgs(0,a)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
PrintArgs(0,a)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact snipped you tested in the Windows Console (I guess this means within a `.py` script) and in python shell? This should result in `IndentationError: unexpected indent` for both. --- And if you fix the indentation, you're still iterating over something different than the list from the first line, as [Scipio mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31485794/674064).

Comment: Discard your except blocks and give us the real error tracebacks; you are throwing useful information away with those non-handlers. Knowing the value of `arg` would be helpful too. And don't call a variable `list` that confusing at best and broken at worst.

Comment: @msw apologies for not providing the actual code, I was manually typing it without the editor as I was not near my workstation. I have updated the question again.

Answer (score 1):

In the code example you've provided you define a list i, then you iterate over a collection called list you never initiated, and assign the values in this list to i, thus dropping the original value. I guess you only provided a part of your code, please provide a minimum working example.

If I try to reproduce your problem, I only get a type error, for iterating over a list which is not initialized.

Comment: Ok, now you now iterate through the right list. But instead of taking the i'th item in the list and trying to print its integer value you take the item, cast it to int and try to print the "item'th" item in the list. So first you print the second item(as the first item has index 0) which is correcly printed out as 'a' when I test the code. You then proceed to print the a'th item of the list, which would be the 98th, with 97 being the Ascii-value of a lower case a. With the list only featuring 2 items this produces an error.

Comment: apologies for not providing the actual code, I am manually typing it without the editor as I was not near my workstation. I have updated the question again.

Comment: You are not using the arguments handed over to your script in any way. First you discard the first argument by only handing over the second to n-th item to your function(use [] instead of [1:]). Plus within the function you do not use the parameters, you operate only on the list initialized there. Plus you still use the items of the list as index for the very same list, thus creating errors as there is no third element.

Comment: sys.argv[] gives SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax at []

Comment: I am using the parameters, I am looping through the arguments provided: 
for i in arg: ...

Comment: Ok, you are right on the args-related stuff. Sorry for that one, i rarely use this syntax. Now i don't really get what you need the list for. Because, what you are still doing is taking the parameters as indeces to you list, so for input zero you do print(list[int(0)]) which of course prints the first element o the list, 1. Then you do print(list[int(a)]) which afaik leads to print(list[97]). As there is no 98th element it throws an error.

Comment: Why would print int(a) lead to print list[97]? And if it does, shouldnt it through and IndexError?

Comment: In the code you provide in your question it says 'print(list[int(i)])'. So you use the Integer representation of whatever i is as an index to your list and try to print the corresponding item. Now, if a is considered a char, int(a) should afaik return its ASCII-value, which is 97. I think you should get some kind of out-of-bounds error. I think the code you provided could still be differing from the code you're actually testing.